# How can I use .live() with chained selectors in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code:

```
$('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { 
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
});
```

This affects all datepickers on the page. I want to target a specific datepicker, so I do this:

```
var specificPicker = $(this).datepicker("widget");
```

I then want to do:

```
$(specificPicker).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function() { 
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
});
```

but `live()` does not support chaining.

The documentation suggests that `live()` is deprecated, and I should use `on()` but if I replace either of the two methods of calling with `.on` instead of `.live`, it doesn't work.

How can I get this working?

Comment: Could you define the error you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that due to the way `.live()` works. It attaches the event to the document itself and then checks if the element the event comes from matches the selector from the `$('...')` used right before calling `.live()`.

The correct way to use `.on()` is this:

```
$('existing-element-selector')
    .on('mouseleave', '.dynamic-element-selector', callbackFunction);
```

In your case that would be this:

```
$(specificPicker).on('mouseleave', '.ui-datepicker-calendar tr', function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Worked great thanks. Unfortunately it seems that despite doing it to the specific picker it triggers for all datepickers as they use the same div and don't use a unique id, but I can fix that!

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `.live()` with `.on()` is not a find-and-replace operation.

You need to change this:

```
$("selector").live("event", handler);
```

To this:

```
$("base-selector").on("event", "descendant-selector", handler);
```

The values of `base-selector` and `descendant-selector` have to be derived from the initial `selector`; you can use `document` as `base-selector` and set `descendant-selector` to whatever `selector` was for a straight-up conversion.

So, in order to achieve the same behavior as this:

```
$(specificPicker).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr')
.live('mouseleave', function() { 
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
});
```

Do this:

```
$(specificPicker).on("mouseleave", '.ui-datepicker-calendar tr', function() { 
    $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to stick with the version of jQuery you are using, and therefore stick with using `live()`, try this...

```
$(specificPicker).find('.ui-datepicker-calendar tr').each(function() {
    $(this).live('mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover');
    });
});
```

Just use `each()` to parse the selected elements and attach the event handler to them.